# CSS not applying to all elements of the same type?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am attempting to style the horizontal rule elements on my site (or separators, as Wordpress likes to call them). I have added the CSS to my style sheet, but for some reason, the styling is not applying to all instances of horizontal rule.

I am very new to web development and this is my first time amending style.css. I feel I may be missing something obvious.

I have added the following to the top of style.css:

```
hr  {
    background-color:#06185F !important;
    height:0.5px !important;
}
```

I expected that styling to apply across all horizontal rule elements on my site. However, it appears to be applying inconsistently, as seen here: https://emotionallyhealthyschools.org/whole-school-approach/

The middle of the three separators I have used in the body of this page is showing with a different style to the other 2. Please advise?

Comment: Also there is `.wp-block-separator.is-style-wide {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}` in your style.min.css

Comment: Hi dgknca, I have removed that styling from style.min.css and it hasn't made a difference, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css seems to be fine - However, it's actually the middle `hr` that is displayed correctly with a height of 0.5px.

I would actuall refrain from dimensioning below 1px because of potential unintended renderings due to rounding errors. If you add

```
min-height: 1px;
```

the `hr`s are rendered with the same height.

Answer (score 0):

> add the CSS in bottom of the style.css

Comment: Hi Sunil, I have moved the styling to the bottom of style.css and unfortunately it has not made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap is adding some styling, including a `border-top` value to your `hr`.
add `border-top: none` or `border-top: unset` and it should work as expected.

Also change your `px-value` to a full px. 
with pixels you either have one or not, there aren't half-values.

Comment: Hi rebecca - I added the code you suggested and it actually made the middle separator disappear entirely! Now I'm totally baffled...

Comment: it's because of 0.5 px. you either have a px or not, there are no half values

Comment: Hi rebecca, I have changed it to 1px and the middle separator is still invisible. I'm struggling to understand why 3 identical elements are being treated differently by my stylesheet. Apologies, I'm very new to this.

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm not sure i understand correctly? is it working now or not? or do you just want a general explanation?